# Fiware IotAgent: can't send command to a device

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I approvisionned my device like this in the IoT agent:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.1.110:80/iot/devices \
-i \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: egmsmartcity" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /egmsmartcitypath" \
-d ' { "devices": [ { "device_id": "test",
 "entity_name": "sensors:test",
 "entity_type": "sensors",
"protocol": "PDI-IoTA-MQTT-UltraLight",
 "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
 "endpoint": "notUsed",
 "commands": [{ "name": "ping", "type": "command", "value": ""}]  } ] }'
```

It is successufl registered in the context Broker:

GET on: http://192.168.1.77:1026/v1/contextEntities/sensors:test

with headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Fiware-Service: egmsmartcity
Fiware-ServicePath: /egmsmartcitypath
```

I got the following response:

```
{
contextElement: {
type: "sensors"
isPattern: "false"
id: "sensors:test"
attributes: [1]
0:  {
name: "TimeInstant"
type: "ISO8601"
value: "2015-11-30T16:53:45.556269Z"
}-
-
}-
statusCode: {
code: "200"
reasonPhrase: "OK"
}-
}
```

and then when I try to update the command like this:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.1.77:1026/v1/updateContext \
     -i \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: egmsmartcity" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /egmsmartcitypath" \
-d ' {"updateAction":"UPDATE","contextElements":[{"id":"sensors:test","type":"sensors","isPattern":"false","attributes":[{"name":"ping","type":"command","value":"22" } ]} ]}'
```

I got this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 157
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 17:05:11 GMT

<updateContextResponse>
  <errorCode>
    <code>404</code>
    <reasonPhrase>No context element found</reasonPhrase>
  </errorCode>
</updateContextResponse>
```

why is it returning "No context element found" ? What have I missed ? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

**[Updates]**
I tried a simple get on "/iot/devices"
Here is the log in the Iot Agent lg file:

In case the operation was successuful, from localhost

```
HTTP Version:  1.1
Resource requested: /iot/devices
Resource delivered: /iot/devices
Query string 
Content length: 0
Headers: Fiware-ServicePath: /egmsmartcitypath
Fiware-Service: egmsmartcity
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*

time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,516.800CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=operator() | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:396] | msg=Processing request /iot-754c76a3-b95a-4aac-976a-08ab37119c05-34 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,516.813CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=execute_filters | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:410] | msg=Processing request /iot-754c76a3-b95a-4aac-976a-08ab37119c05-34 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,516.820CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=execute_filters | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:411] | msg=execute_filters status:  200 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,516.953CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140374294497024:media_filter.cc:56] | msg=MediaFilter handle_request /iot-754c76a3-b95a-4aac-976a-08ab37119c05-34/iot/devices 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,516.982CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140374294497024:media_filter.cc:95] | msg=Accept: */* 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.035CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_end_filters | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:446] | msg=Processing request /iot-754c76a3-b95a-4aac-976a-08ab37119c05-34 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.046CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_end_filters | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:447] | msg=End filters status 200 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.056CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:492] | msg=Processing request /iot-754c76a3-b95a-4aac-976a-08ab37119c05-34 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.062CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:493] | msg=Proccessing in handle /iot 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.180CET | lvl= INFO | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=devices | file=[140373934458624:admin_service.cc:586] | msg=iota::AdminService::devices method:GET trace_message:/iot-754c76a3-b95a-4aac-976a-08ab37119c05-34 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.215CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=get_all_devices_json | file=[140373934458624:admin_service.cc:1748] | msg=get_all_devices_json service=egmsmartcity service_path=/egmsmartcitypath detailed= 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.234CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=conn | file=[140373934458624:mongo_connection.cc:261] | msg=MongoConnection::conn returns 0x20ba8f0 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.262CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=count | file=[140373934458624:collection.cc:833] | msg=Collection:count bbdd=iot.DEVICE options= query={ service: "egmsmartcity", service_path: "/egmsmartcitypath" } 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.524CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=find | file=[140373934458624:collection.cc:704] | msg=Collection:find bbdd=iot.DEVICE query={ service: "egmsmartcity", service_path: "/egmsmartcitypath" } limit=20 offset=0 options=-2147483648 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.546CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=find | file=[140373934458624:collection.cc:718] | msg=before getConnection 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.553CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=find | file=[140373934458624:collection.cc:723] | msg=before query 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.737CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=create_response | file=[140373934458624:admin_service.cc:1309] | msg=create_response: 200 { "count": 2,"devices": [{ "device_id" : "sensorTmp" },{ "device_id" : "test" }]} 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.766CET | lvl= INFO | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=devices | file=[140373934458624:admin_service.cc:718] | msg=iota::AdminService::devices method:GET trace_message:/iot-754c76a3-b95a-4aac-976a-08ab37119c05-34 code: 200 response:{ "count": 2,"devices": [{ "device_id" : "sensorTmp" },{ "device_id" : "test" }]} 
time=2015-12-02T10:41:41,517.902CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=finish | file=[140373934458624:rest_handle.cc:567] | msg=finish connection 2
```

In case the operation was not successuful, from Rest client

```
HTTP Version:  1.1
Resource requested: /iot/devices/
Resource delivered: /iot/devices/
Query string 
Content length: 0
Headers: Fiware-ServicePath: /egmsmartcitypath
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Fiware-Service: egmsmartcity
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 192.168.1.110
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json

time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.079CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=operator() | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:396] | msg=Processing request /iot-c7a1ab03-73e6-4f9b-82de-d8f569927296-33 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.079CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=execute_filters | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:410] | msg=Processing request /iot-c7a1ab03-73e6-4f9b-82de-d8f569927296-33 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.079CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=execute_filters | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:411] | msg=execute_filters status:  200 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.156CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140374294497024:media_filter.cc:56] | msg=MediaFilter handle_request /iot-c7a1ab03-73e6-4f9b-82de-d8f569927296-33/iot/devices/ 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.191CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140374294497024:media_filter.cc:95] | msg=Accept: */* 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.338CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_end_filters | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:446] | msg=Processing request /iot-c7a1ab03-73e6-4f9b-82de-d8f569927296-33 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.350CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_end_filters | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:447] | msg=End filters status 200 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.360CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:492] | msg=Processing request /iot-c7a1ab03-73e6-4f9b-82de-d8f569927296-33 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.366CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=handle_request | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:493] | msg=Proccessing in handle /iot 
time=2015-12-02T10:39:55,246.586CET | lvl=DEBUG | comp=iota:IoTAgent-MQTT-UL20 | op=finish | file=[140373942851328:rest_handle.cc:567] | msg=finish connection 2
```

Seems like the iot agent finish the opration before teminating the request handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the IoT Agent has not been able to answer the updateContext request. When you declare an attribute as a command, the IoT Agent registers itself as the Context Provider of that attribute for the Device's entity in the Context Broker. If an UPDATE request comes to the CB for that attribute, that request will be forwarded to the IoTA. If the IoTA can't answer or is not found, the request will fail.

The probable cause of this problem is the misconfiguration of the public IP. If the Context Broker can't find the provider of the attribute you want to update, it will return a 404 error. Did you configure the public IP in your IoT Agent?

Comment: the IoT Agent and the Context Broker are in the same local network and I can ping the IoT Agent from the Context Broker, I checked also the firewall in the IoT agent and it is disabled (iptables.service and firewalld.service )